# C: How to prevent dataloss on crashing from using mmap?

Tags: caching, mmap

I was doing some research on how databases prevents dataloss from writing to page cache using mmap. I don't understand how the memory mapped not lost upon crashing. Could anyone tell me how it really works?

Comment: Upon *what* crashing?  The database program?  Some hardware component? The whole machine?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'm sorry. I mean the database program crashes (like "kill -9"), not crashes of hardware or the whole machine.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877797/how-does-mmap-work ? Maybe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does mmap work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877797/how-does-mmap-work)

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is a dupe, but I remain a little uncertain about what is being asked.  Why *should* a program crash cause data loss via mapped memory?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Maybe the program crashed while writing to the page cache, will the data suppose to write to the file lost?

Comment: If the _system_ crashes (e.g. kernel panic, hardware failure/freezeup, etc) all bets are off. But, if a program is terminated (even with `kill -9`) _anything_ written into a mapped page will be flushed (eventually--by the kernel) to the backing store (e.g. the mapped file). Remember the _kernel_ isn't crashing, just the _program_. The kernel is still around to do cleanup. From the app's perspective it is a crash. From the kernel's perspective, this is just an app exit/termination

Comment: I thought there is no guarantee that the page cached will write to hardware without calling msync() @CraigEstey . Also, what will happen if the data was only written half way to page cached when crashed?

Comment: Re. `msync`: _Without  use of  this  call,  there  is  no  guarantee that changes are written back before munmap(2) is called_. But, `munmap` is [implicitly/effectively] called when the program is terminated. `msync` is only if you wish to _force_ the flush early. As to partial data, that is different. If you write byte 0 to page A but get killed _before_ writing byte 1 to page B (or page A for that matter), only the first byte will be flushed

Comment: Loosely, in general, to prevent data loss, databases write out things in a precise order, do a sync, then do more data. (e.g.) they write a journal record, force a sync to disk, then rewrite the actual data to a block. The data is written to a _different_ block [so the original data is still in the old block], and then the block _mapping_ is changed and written to disk. So, the database stays whole. It either sees the old state or the new state but not a partial mixing. And, recovery is possible because of the journal. This is mostly for _system_ crashes